# O que exatamente faz essa declaração de Python?

Tags: python, sklearn

Estou estudando o módulo sklearn de Python, e me deparei com essa declaração:

```
data = pd.read_csv('car.data')

X = data[[
    'buying',
    'maint',
    'safety'
]].values
```

O que exatamente é armazenado em X? Porque a declaração é feita com dois []?

Answer (score 3):

No exemplo você está passando uma lista de `chaves` com os nomes das colunas que você quer extrair do *DataFrame* `data` e dessas colunas você extrai o que tem lá dentro como valores de NumPy através da função [pandas.DataFrame.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)

O que vai estar armazenado em 'X' depende dos dados que estão nas colunas (que batem o nome com a lista) do arquivo que você importou.

> Porque a declaração é feita com dois []?

Porquê você quer passar uma lista (primeiro colchete) para procurar dentro da *DataFrame* 'data' (segundo colchete).